# Search query to find a word thats could be in inside multiple properties

Tags: c#, linq, episerver, episerver-find

I have three properties

```
First name
Last name
Username
```

User can search for a word that can be in all three properties. I have had this two queries to achieve the desired result

```
searchTermFilters = searchTermFilters
.For(term)
.InFields(x => x.Firstname, x => x.Surname, x => x.Username);


searchTermFilters = searchTermFilters
            .OrFilter(x => x.Firstname.AnyWordBeginsWith(term))
            .OrFilter(x => x.Surname.AnyWordBeginsWith(term))
            .OrFilter(x => x.Username.AnyWordBeginsWith(term));
```

The issue is that for both of them it matches exactly. I want something like `.Contains` in Linq. Any insights?

Comment: Did you try `bool string.Contains(string substring)`, or `List<string>.Contains(string s)` ?

Comment: yes I did. Didn't worked

Comment: Could you add additional `OrFilter` with `MatchCaseInsensitive` to also find exact matches?

Answer (score 1):

Use this way with **Or** condition

```
searchTermFilters.Filter(x => x.Firstname.Contains(term) | 
                         x => x.Lastname.Contains(term) |
                         x => x.Username.Contains(term))
```

Comment: This works unless OP is about finding strings that strictly either _begins_ or _exactly matches_ the string. If it's OK for the string to appear anywhere, this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score -2):

For single Filter=>

```
searchTermFilters = searchTermFilters.Where(w=>w.FirstName.Contains(term)).ToList();
```

For Multi Filter=>

```
searchTermFilters = searchTermFilters.Where(w=>w.FirstName.Contains(term) || w.Surname.Contains(term)).ToList();
```

Hope this help.

Comment: The OP is about the Episerver Find search service, so this answer does not apply.